# Removing Incorrect WINS record

Tags: networking, dns, samba, bind9, netbios

So I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server that I'm trying to get to run as a Domain Controller for a set of Windows machines.

I've set up a Bind9 DNS and it works fine, pinging the nameserver gives the correct IP: `192.168.0.3`.

However pinging the Netbios name gives `192.168.0.255` which is wrong, I saw a similar problem on the Unix and Linux stack exchange which said to run `nmblookup -U 192.168.0.3 -R 'NETBIOS_NAME'`

This gives:

```
192.168.0.255 Arc<00>
192.168.0.3 Arc<00>
192.168.1.1 Arc<00>
```

The last two records are correct, but the first... I don't even know why or how that got there. I have no idea where that record is, my only `WINS` server is samba, but even if I set:

```
wins support = no
```

That entry (`.255`) doesn't go away.

Answer (score 2):

On debian,

```
# service smbd stop
# service nmbd stop
# find / -name gencache.tdb -o -name wins.tdb -o -name wins.dat | xargs rm
# service smbd start
# service nmbd start
```

For me the WINS entry that was ruining my day was located in /var/lib/samba/wins.dat

Good luck.

Comment: For testing Samba wins server entries on windows: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830578

Answer (score 0):

```
# on CentOS 7
# service smb stop
# service nmb stop
# tdbdump /var/lib/samba/wins.tdb |grep <the entry you're looking to get rid of>
# tdbtool /var/lib/samba/wins.tdb delete <the data from and including the first double quote after the equal sign to the last double quote>
# service nmb start
# service nmb start
```

An example

```
# tdbdump /var/lib/samba/wins.tdb |grep NADA
```

key(65) = "NADA\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\1E"
key(65) = "NADA\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00"

```
# tdbtool delete "NADA\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\1E"
# tdbtool delete "NADA\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00"
```